# OnClickListener working at padding area

Tags: android, layout

I want to make that when I add `ClickListener` to `@id/content` it should work at whole area within `RelativeLayout` on the left of `@id/group_indicator`. Not only at selected area below. Analogously I want the same for `@id/group_indicator`.

I guess it's because of `android:padding` in `RelativeLayout` but I don't know how to make it work.

More of this, why height of `@id/content` and `@id/group_indicator` aren't equal? Both of them are aligned to parent bottom and top.

#### My layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_card_background"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Test text"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/group_indicator" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/group_indicator"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

#### Output:

[image: my output]

If the title is incorrect, please fix it, I'm not sure if it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

You cant actually listen to the padding when you click on the eddittext, because it is part of the relative layout.

Solution:

Create a parent view to the TextView and remove the 
PAdding of the relativelayout and add the padding to the parentview(this parentview is inside the relative layout) and use that parentview for listening to the onclick so youll have the whole area to listen in onClick.